# How to change relative symlinked path to "actual" one (in ranger or terminal)

Tags: linux, shell-script, zsh, symlink, ranger

*What is actual path?* Consider folder **A** in the file system and a symlinked **B** to it. Consider currently in ranger (or terminal) inside a sub-directory within **B** such as `/home/B/sub1/sub2` which is in fact `/another_but_actual_path/A/sub1/sub2`. What I want is to have a tool/command/script which convert the relative path to the actual path. I mean while `pwd` shows `/home/B/sub1/sub2`, I want to access the path `/another_but_actual_path/A/sub1/sub2`.

p.s. I tried `readlink` but it couldn't give me the actual path.

p.s. I don't know if so called actual path has a name or not.

Comment: The `realpath` command?

Comment: @StephenHarris, yep!

Comment: @StephenHarris, if you can please provide the answer with some more useful information to get approved or feel free to remove the whole question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Linux "coreutils" package contains a command `realpath`.

This will follow any and all symbolics links for the named path, and return the "real" path associated with it.

So:

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar
$ ln -s /tmp/foo $HOME/foo
$ realpath $HOME/foo
/tmp/foo
$ realpath $HOME/foo/bar
/tmp/foo/bar
$ realpath $HOME/foo/bar/baz
/tmp/foo/bar/baz
```

We can see that the link `$HOME/foo` is being replaced by the real path of `/tmp/foo`.

The last entry need not exist, but all intermediate points must.

```
$ realpath $HOME/foo/bar/baz/qux
realpath: '/home/sweh/foo/bar/baz/qux': No such file or directory
```

That's because there is no `baz` directory.

Comment: based on this I tried `map gR cd "$(realpath $(pwd))"` in ranger config (`rc.conf`) but it dident' work. It might be due to something with ranger and how it represent the path but any clue?

Answer (score 1):

In Ranger you can use the `gl` and `gL` commands. Type `g`, then:

```
key          command
 L           cd -r %f
 l           cd -r .
```